Why should there not be a factor 1/2 in this variational Bayesian derivation? (Question about simplification/mathematical manipulation)
I derived variational Bayesian independent component analysis (VB ICA) as in Choudrey's PhD thesis "Variational Methods for Bayesian Independent Component Analysis" in detail. I get the same expressions as him for all parameters except for two, namely $\hat{\mu}_{i,q_i}^t$ and $\hat{m}_{A_{ji}}$. In my derivations, these parameters are $\hat{\mu}_{ikn}$ and $\hat{m}_{ji}$. The issue is the same for both and originates from the same maths. I get a factor 1/2 for the last terms of these two parameters and Choudrey doesn't. I've attached the relevant piece of maths for the derivation of $\hat{\mu}_{ikn}$ 1, but I'll write it out here as well. No background in variational Bayes is necessary (I think).
$ \begin{aligned} &q^*(\boldsymbol{S},\boldsymbol{Z}) \propto exp\left(\underset{-\boldsymbol{S},\boldsymbol{Z}}{E}\left\{ \log p(\boldsymbol{X}\mid \boldsymbol{S},\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{\Lambda})p(\boldsymbol{S} \mid \boldsymbol{Z}, \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\lambda} ) p(\boldsymbol{Z} \mid \boldsymbol {\pi}) \right\}\right) \\ & \propto exp\left( \underset{-\boldsymbol{S},\boldsymbol{Z}}{E}\left\{ \sum_n \sum_j \left[ -\frac{\Lambda_j}{2}(x_{nj}-(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{s}_n)_j)^2 \right] \right. \right. \\
& \left. \left. + \sum_n \sum_i \sum_k z_{ink} \left[\frac{1}{2}\log\lambda_{ik} - \frac{\lambda_{ik}}{2}(s_{ni}-\mu_{ik})^2 \right] \right. \right. \\
& \left. \left. +\sum_n\sum_i\sum_k z_{ink}\log \pi_{ik} \right\} \right) \end{aligned} $
Only the terms depending on $\boldsymbol{S}$ and $\boldsymbol{Z}$ are kept. The distributions $p(\boldsymbol{X}\mid \boldsymbol{S},\boldsymbol{A},\boldsymbol{\Lambda})$ and $p(\boldsymbol{S} \mid \boldsymbol{Z}, \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\lambda} )$ are Gaussians described in terms of precisions $\Lambda_j$ and $\lambda_{ik}$ respectively. Up to here, I believe everything is correct. Next, I multiplied everything out and wrote matrix operations in terms of scalar sums. $\boldsymbol{A}$ is an $M\times L$ matrix and $\boldsymbol{s}_n$ is an $L \times 1$ vector.
$\begin{aligned} &q^*(\boldsymbol{S},\boldsymbol{Z}) \propto exp\left(\underset{-\boldsymbol{S},\boldsymbol{Z}}{E}\left\{ \sum_n \sum_j \left[ -\frac{\Lambda_j}{2}\left(x_{nj}^2-2x_{nj}\sum_{i=1}^LA_{ji}s_{ni} + \sum_{i=1}^LA_{ji}s_{ni}\sum_{i=1}^LA_{ji}s_{ni} \right) \right] \right. \right. \\
& \left. \left. + \sum_n \sum_i \sum_k z_{ink} \left[\frac{1}{2}\log\lambda_{ik} - \frac{\lambda_{ik}}{2}(s_{ni}^2-2\mu_{ik}s_{ni} + \mu_{ik}^2) \right] +\sum_n\sum_i\sum_k z_{ink}\log \pi_{ik} \right\} \right) \\
& \propto exp\left(\underset{-\boldsymbol{S},\boldsymbol{Z}}{E}\left\{ \sum_n \sum_j \left[ -\frac{\Lambda_j}{2}\left(x_{nj}^2-2x_{nj}\sum_{i=1}^LA_{ji}s_{ni} + \sum_{i=1}^LA_{ji}^2 s_{ni}^2+\sum_{i=1}^L \sum_{\substack{u=1\\ u \neq i}}^L A_{ji}s_{ni}A_{ju}s_{nu} \right) \right] \right. \right. \\
& \left. \left. + \sum_n \sum_i \sum_k z_{ink} \left[\frac{1}{2}\log\lambda_{ik} - \frac{\lambda_{ik}}{2}(s_{ni}^2-2\mu_{ik}s_{ni} + \mu_{ik}^2) \right] +\sum_n\sum_i\sum_k z_{ink}\log \pi_{ik} \right \} \right)  \end{aligned}$
The next step is to group the coefficients of $s_{ni}^2$ and $s_{ni}$. Since the $\boldsymbol{S}$ part of the posterior, $q^*(\boldsymbol{S}\mid \boldsymbol{Z})$, will be a Gaussian, the new precision and mean will form the coefficients of $s_{ni}^2$ and $s_{ni}$. Furthermore, a sum over $k$ can be introduced since $\sum_k z_{ink}=1$.
$\begin{aligned} q^*(\boldsymbol{S},\boldsymbol{Z}) & \propto exp\left(\underset{-\boldsymbol{S},\boldsymbol{Z}}{E}\left\{ \sum_n \sum_i \sum_k z_{ink} \left[ -\frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_j \Lambda_j A_{ji}^2 + \lambda_{ik} \right)s_{ni}^2 \right. \right. \right. \\
& \left. \left. \left. + \left(\sum_j \Lambda_j x_{nj} A_{ji} - \sum_j \frac{\Lambda_j}{2} \sum_{u \neq i} A_{ji}A_{ju}s_{nu} + \lambda_{ik} \mu_{ik}\right) s_{ni} + \frac{1}{2}\log\lambda_{ik} - \frac{\lambda_{ik}}{2} \mu_{ik}^2\right] \right. \right. \\
& \left. \left. +\sum_n\sum_i\sum_k z_{ink}\log \pi_{ik} \right \} \right) \end{aligned}$
Reading the precision and mean off and using $\langle \cdot \rangle$ as a shorthand for expectation, I get
$\hat{\lambda}_{ik}=\sum_j \langle \Lambda_j \rangle \langle A_{ji}^2 \rangle + \langle \lambda_{ik} \rangle $, which is correct and
$\hat{\mu}_{ikn} = \frac{1}{\hat{\lambda}_{ik}} \left[ \langle \mu_{ik} \rangle \langle \lambda_{ik}\rangle + \sum_j \langle \Lambda_j \rangle \langle A_{ji} \rangle \left(x_{nj}-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{u \neq i} \langle A_{ju} \rangle \langle s_{nu} \rangle \right) \right]$ which is incorrect because of the $\frac{1}{2}$ which should not be there.
I implemented the code and the factor 1/2 should indeed not be there. I'm not sure how to derive the maths to get rid of it. I checked the splitting of the double sum into diagonal and off-diagonal elements and it looks correct to me. If there was a factor 2 in front of the off-diagonals, it would solve the issue, but I don't think there should be one.
Any insights/thoughts about why the $\frac{1}{2}$ should/shouldn't be there will be much appreciated.
